# how two linux embedded device can communicate on ethernet

Tags: linux, networking

i am a beginer in network things...

I am m trying to make a communication between two linux device(imx-6 boards). 
These devices are connected through an ethernet cable. The devive will not be connected to the local LAN. 
What i am trying is to make a communication between these two devices using ethernet.

With the Cross cable connected and assigned static IP for both device by 
enabling below code in /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.0.XX
     network 192.168.0.0
     netmask 255.255.255.0

the ping is NOT happening between device (also the network port lights are also not coming) , 
But when i connected one of this device to laptop (made static IP to laptop) it pings.

am i missing something ???
i am using Timesys Nitrogen 6X board (https://linuxlink.timesys.com/docs/gsg/NITROGEN6X#SECTION00042000000000000000)

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 6
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Link detected: no
```

PLease suggest me an approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Connect the devices via a [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable), if the NICs don't support [Auto-MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX#Auto-MDIX).

Assign them [static IP addresses](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/) on the same subnet. Eg:

```
A: 192.168.100.20  255.255.255.0
B: 192.168.100.30  255.255.255.0
```

Proceed with your application protocols as you would any other network programming.

Comment: with the above setting (static IP for both device and a crossover cable) the ping is not happening between device (the network port lights are also not coming) , But when i connected one of this device to laptop (made static IP to laptop) it pings.  am i missing something ???

Comment: Okay, you verified one device. What about the other? Also, make sure firewall is disabled during initial tests.

Comment: both the device are able to communicate with laptop...
but my intention is to make communication between these two devices which am not getting thru

Comment: i have modified the question ... added more details on what i am trying to do